# How to run Gunicorn inside virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, gunicorn

## Background

I'm currently configuring a Nginx + Gunicorn + Django + virtualenv setup. I have a `prod_settings` which will be used for production, and set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variables to it by adding `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.prod_settings` to `project/venv/bin/activate`. This works perfectly if I first run `source project/venv/bin/activate`.

Now I followed [Instructions from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04#installing-the-packages-from-the-ubuntu-repositories) to use `systemd` to monitor Gunicorn.

Inside `gunicorn.service` file, I have `ExecStart=/path/to/project/venv/bin/gunicorn`.

## Problem

1. If `.../venv/bin/gunicorn` runs inside virtualenv, will it activate virtualenv if I call this command from a system environment?
2. Also, I'm absolutely sure that calling  `.../venv/bin/gunicorn` from system env won't trigger `source /project/venv/activate` as the env variables are not defined.
3. Since `.../venv/bin/gunicorn` can be run from the system env, I wonder how it finds the `lib` of the virtualenv, instead of `lib` of the system?

This is how `../venv/bin/gunicorn` looks

```py
#!/home/hao/Eng-Memo/venv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

Some reference resources can be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally figured this out. According to [Python Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> You don’t specifically need to activate a virtual environment, as you
> can just specify the full path to that environment’s Python
> interpreter when invoking Python. Furthermore, all scripts installed
> in the environment should be runnable without activating it.
>
> In order to achieve this, scripts installed into virtual environments
> have a “shebang” line which points to the environment’s Python
> interpreter, i.e. #!//bin/python. This means that the
> script will run with that interpreter regardless of the value of PATH.
> On Windows, “shebang” line processing is supported if you have the
> Python Launcher for Windows installed. Thus, double-clicking an
> installed script in a Windows Explorer window should run it with the
> correct interpreter without the environment needing to be activated or
> on the PATH.

So the first line of `../venv/bin/gunicorn`, which looks like a comment actually plays a huge role. It specifies the Python interpreter to be used is the one of `virtualenv`. Hence, `sys.path` will add the `site-packages` folder inside `lib` of the `virtualenv`.

Comment: The 1st line that looks like a comment is called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and actually is a directive to Unix/Linux kernels what interpreter to run for this particular file.